# Milkman Games iOS in-app purchase for Adobe AIR example never completes purchase in app store

Tags: ios, air, in-app-purchase

I bought the iOS in-app purchase native extension for Adobe Flash/AIR from Milkman Games but am running into a problem, maybe others have seen it in their testing (I am corresponding with the author about it, but it doesn’t sound like something he has run into).

When I follow the example and instructions carefully for a non-consumable in-app purchase, it asks me (on my iPad):

1. Confirm Your in-app purchase [Environment Sandbox]
2. Gets my Apple ID/password
3. Verification Required [Environment: Sandbox]
4. Password again
5. Goes to the app store
6. dialog box with [Environment: Sandbox], background box says “Loading…”
7. Password again...

Then it endlessly repeats steps 6 and 7, never completing the purchase. I know my password is correct because when I enter it incorrectly, I get a warning message about it.

Has anyone seen something like this? Thanks for any insights you might provide!

Comment: hey, user150812

Is your problem solved by using this ANE? I am thinkingto purchase this ANE? And I have not found any FAQ related to it. So, I thought to ask. Share your exerience?

Comment: Hi, just saw your comment -- I have been using the ANE since mid 2013 fine, it works well. I simply went too far in the process of registering my test user, I just had to create the test user, then when I went to make the purchase, I would click the purchase and sign in as the test user. When iOS 7 came out, I had to replace the ANE with an update provided by Milkman Games (restore transactions wasn't working properly), but since doing that, I have had no issues at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign out of itunes in the settings on the ipad first. Then when you log into your app use your test account. It won't ask you to go through payment information or any other info.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a wild shot but are you using a live Apple id account or a testing Apple id account?

When I set up an in app purchase (not using ANE though) I remember something similar.

iTunes Connect, Manage Users, Test User. Create a user account and use these settings for testing.

Comment: thanks for trying, but I was using a test user. I don't know if it is normal during testing, but the app store background when I go to do a test purchase continues to say "Loading" with the loading animation (of course I haven't loaded real content into the store, so there isn't anything there to load, but I thought for testing perhaps they would show something there).

Comment: Thanks again crooksy88, it looks like the problem could have been I took the test user too far in the registration process. I made a test user in iTunes Connect, then online I went through email verification and the like, and reviewing/filling out the profile. I even had to add a real credit card (which I then removed).

I created a new test user, but did not "Review" or fill out those details when prompted (on iPad). Could also be just creating another test user (as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchase-problem)

Comment: I really don't know if it was not filling in the details, or creating a second user. The clue to me was the first time I tried it, when I went to buy the product, it would switch over to the iTunes Store and I'd see the error message in the sample code go to "Failed to connect to iTunes", which is what prompted my search to find the related question I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This password loop occurs when you are NOT using a US test account.

Create a US test account reset the ipad and choose US.

Test.