# Payment queue observer returns "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error, why?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

`func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)`

delegate method delivers  *"Cannot connect to iTunes Store"* error. Why? I try to set up In-App purchase. Anything wrong in iTunes Connect setting? I am following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnSUl5_ccp0) tutorial.

I am testing on real device. I get the error message before blue popup to authenticate myself as testuser.

I might have problem with my profession profiles? To distribution profile no devices is attached?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you testing this on? In-App purchases can only be tested on a real device and not the simulator.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchase-problem

Comment: Also, you need a to be using a test Apple ID, which can be created in iTunesConnect

Comment: okay... There are a lot of reasons for this to happen, and this problem is quite common as well. I'm pretty sure if you look around the various answers in SO you should find what is wrong.

Comment: When did you create the product? Have you regenerated and replaced the provisioning profile after enabling in-app purchase in the developer portal?

Comment: I have done a lot of stuff, recreating project in an other name etc., publish, but only **before** enabling in-app purchase

Comment: Well, you are supposed to generate new provisioning profiles for the application after you have enabled in-app purchase for a particular app ID. Sync XCode with your developer account and then confirm whether the fresh profile is associated with your application.

Comment: I noted that 0 devices is assigned to Distribution Provision profile, can it be the reason?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with your distribution profile. While in development (and testing in-app purchase) the development profile is all that matters. Download the development profile, and double-click on it. Attach it to your app, then Clean and Rebuild the application.

Answer (score 0):

Sign out in App Store and try the In-App purchase again. Then try with test user.

Comment: yes it works finally, thanks you help, I just sign out in App Store, strange isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You cant test IAP with your real account. First you must sign out and sign in with test account that you create in itunnes (sandbox).