# Payment queue does not call observer object about updated transaction, why?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

When user press `BUY` and payment is added ..

```
@IBAction func buyProduct(sender: AnyObject) {

    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
}
```

.. I would expect that a blue popup comes up to approve purchase, and then observer will get called.

But not in my case. Any idea why? Anything wrong in my iTunes Connect?

Before when viewController was loaded I called

`SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` which returns true and I started a product request:

```
let pr = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: "com.xxx"))
pr.delegate = self
pr.start()
```

and `func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!)` delegate was called.

I am using [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnSUl5_ccp0) tutorial

Comment: Have you set the payment queue observer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

before calling

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
```

Comment: it works, btw, do you have any idea why `App can not connect to iTunes Store`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507849/payment-queue-observer-returns-can-not-connect-to-itunes-store-why