# In app purchase cannot connect to itunes store ios 12 following InAppBillingPlugin for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I am trying to test in app purchases in my application following [plugin](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/). Also I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchases) and thousands of other officical/not official articles but there is no result. I do not thins there is a problem in my code because I asked another developer to share me his code and I use it in my app. In his project this code works perfect but I have InAppBillingPurchaseException "Can not connect to Itunes Store". I also logged out of my real accounts before entering sandbox credentials. This is the code but the I do not think the problem is here:

```
public async Task<bool> PurchaseItemAsync()
    {
        var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
        LastExceptionMessage = null;

        try
        {
            var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();
            if (connected == false)
                return false;

            var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(_kProductId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, _kPayload);

            if (purchase == null)
                return false;
            else if (purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
                return true;
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException ex)
        {
            OnPurchaseException(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Dlog.Error("Issue connecting: " + ex);
            LastExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            await billing.DisconnectAsync();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the item In-App Purchase in your app ID?

Comment: How to do that? I do not think the problem is in item id because first of all it must connect to itunes store but it can not

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/in-app-purchasing/in-app-purchase-basics-and-configuration Refer this document

Comment: Yes, I did this steps. But I did not published my app jet. I want to test it in sandbox

Comment: any solution you got it?

Comment: @AdilSaiyad we solved it but we do not know if this was exactly the solution that solved this problem. We think it started to work after filling legal info on the site (ITunesConnect or how it calls.) We think it started to work after filling this: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb6df5ee51. Also after this you need to upload app with a purchase. Probably this two steps can help you.

Comment: @S.Koshelnyk okay after you filling details instant working or after completed banking review and show active status.

Comment: @AdilSaiyad Currently I do not have access to that app. It was on the previous job. Also I updated comment above. Do not remember in details when and after what steps it was solved

Comment: okay, thanks @S.Koshelnyk

Answer (score 0):

In my case, bundleID in my app was not matching with the product id of In App purchase. I had bundle ID **com.xam.sample** in my app code. But product ID was **testiap**. So I created IAP with productID **com.xam.sample.testiap** and I was able to solve that error this way.