# iOS: In App Auto-Renewable Subscription error while purchase [Possible Duplicate]

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have successfully implemented the `in app purchases` for consumable products. And it is working great.

Now i'm getting "Can't connect to iTunes store" when i'm trying to confirm the `auto-renewable subscription`. Is there anything special that we should do for the subscriptions.

Checklist that i have already gone through and verified several times

- Tax, agreements are all set
- Localisation is all set i believe
- Price tier is set
- Tried new sandbox user with multiple territories (UK & Pakistan).
  Store is pakistani right now.

Comment: did you login with internal test user with apple a/c?

Comment: yeah sandbox user

Comment: did you test in device or simulator ?

Comment: using a device (iPhone 6)

Comment: please check solutions provided here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchases

Comment: already tried that, tried again. signed out from all accounts and signed in while purchasing the product, after successful sign in; it went to failure. And got the same message