# In -app purchase live product getting error like : Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

i have implemented in-app purchase in my application and tested with sandbox it is working well. after testing sandbox i have submitted to approval and it is approved by apple currently my product status is ready for sale now  i am testing with iOS 9.0 it is working well but when testing same product with iOS 10 +version its returen me error in fail state Please check attached error

error.code.rawValue: 2, error.code: SKErrorCode, error.errorCode: 2, 2, error.errorUserInfo: ["NSLocalizedDescription": Cannot connect to iTunes Store], ["NSLocalizedDescription": Cannot connect to iTunes Store], error.localizedDescription: Cannot connect to iTunes Store, error.userInfo: ["NSLocalizedDescription": Cannot connect to iTunes Store].

Comment: Do you test it using really account ?

Comment: Yes, with using  in -app purchase promo code

Comment: > can you check this may help [old question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchases)

Comment: @MohamedShaban not working i have already approved product test

Answer (score 0):

iTunes error codes are a mess... Assuming you have your IAPs [configured correctly](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard) since they were working on iOS9, that error is thrown when trying to purchase from a subscription group that is already active for that iTunes account.

Try restoring purchases for that user and see if it works.