# cannot connect to itunes store xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50iTB.png)Hi Thanks in advance i have facing a problem in my xamarin forms ios. Problem is that when i want to purchase product it thrown an exception that cannot to connect to itune store my same code in working fine on xamarin forms android.My code for restore purchases is working fine.

Here is my code for make purchases

```
private async Task<bool> MakePurchase(string ProductId, string Payload)
    {
        if (!CrossInAppBilling.IsSupported)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
        try
        {
            var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

      if (!connected)//Couldn't connect to billing, could be offline, 
   alert user
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("Something went 
                wrong or you may not connected with the internet!");
                return false;
            }

            //try to purchase item
            var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(ProductId, 
            ItemType.InAppPurchase, Payload);

            if (purchase == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Purchased, save this information
                var responseId = purchase.Id;
                var responseToken = purchase.PurchaseToken;
                var state = purchase.State;
                return true;


            }
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException ex)
        {
            if (ex.PurchaseError == PurchaseError.DeveloperError)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("DeveloperError");
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            else if (ex.PurchaseError == PurchaseError.AlreadyOwned)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("AlreadyOwned");
                return true;
            }
            else if(ex.PurchaseError == PurchaseError.BillingUnavailable)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToast> 
           ().Show("BillingUnavailable");
                return false;
            }
             else if(ex.PurchaseError == PurchaseError.InvalidProduct)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("InvalidProduct");
                return false;
            }

             else if(ex.PurchaseError == PurchaseError.ItemUnavailable)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("ItemUnavailable");
                return false;
            }
            else if(ex.PurchaseError == PurchaseError.GeneralError)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("General Error");
                return false;
            }

            //Something bad has occurred, alert user
        }
        finally
        {
            //Disconnect, it is okay if we never connected
            await billing.DisconnectAsync();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Seeing what exception is being thrown and the stack trace helps thanks...

Comment: @FreakyAli  its a general error and inside the general error the message is cannot connect to itune store..

Comment: Where do you see this general error can you show us a screenshot? If not this question is vague and will be marked the same...

Comment: @FreakyAli w8 i just send you the screen shots in 5 to 8 minutes

Comment: @FreakyAlii I add the screen shot and update my question please check it now.

Comment: Are sure sure the credentials are correct?

Comment: yes i just follow this https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/ documentation

Comment: @waheedkhan have you managed to resolve this. Getting the same error and I have tried everything described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchases