# Payment Details not entered issue with iOS InApp Purchases

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have an app that provids consumable in app purchases.

I've implemented this using the library SwiftyStoreKit, everything works smoothly, except for one scenario where the user doesn't have payment details setup in the app store.

In that scenario, the app prompts the user to setup payment details. After the user sets up the payment details, he is prompted to initiate the payment once again on the app store itself. Once the payment is successful, and the user opens the app, an error message is shown, that says 'Could not connect to iTunes'

Hence, I do not know, if the payment was successful or not. And cannot provide that purchase to the user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchases

Comment: this is happening in production, with an actual user, not a sandbox tester

Comment: 'Could not connect to iTunes' is the generic message that's shown for every single SKError, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Okay but, how do i handle a call back when the payment is initiated in the app store, in the scenario the user doesnt have a credit card setup